# Is there a standard generalization of void_t for other types?

Tags: c++, sfinae, c++17

In C++17, we have `std::void_t`, which makes SFINAE look a lot nicer:

```
template <typename T>
std::void_t<decltype(T::prop)> foo() { /* stuff */ }
```

The template function will exist only if `T::prop` exists.

If `T::prop` exists, the template function `foo()` would be equivalent to this:

```
template <typename T>
void foo() { /* stuff */ }
```

Otherwise, the code is equivalent to not declaring `foo()` at all.

Is there any generalization of `std::void_t` for other types in the standard library, such as the following:

```
template<typename T, typename...>
using generic_t = T;
```

so that the code below would be valid?

```
template <typename T>
std::generic_t<int, decltype(T::prop)> foo() { /* stuff */ }
```

which would be equivalent to

```
template <typename T>
int foo() { /* stuff */ }
```

if `T::prop` exists?

Comment: Why not `decltype(T::prop, int())`? Does that not work?

Comment: @Justin Because `std::void_t` ignores the type of its arguments. It will be `void` no matter what.

Comment: I imagine you can do `std::tuple_element_t<0, std::tuple<int, decltype(T::prop)>>`

Comment: `std::conditional_t<true, int, std::void_t<....>>`.

Comment: @Justin I like your suggestion!  It is really succinct and works as long as the type has a constructor that takes no arguments.

Comment: @Bernard If the type doesn't have a default constructor, use [`std::declval`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval).

Comment: @Rakete1111 `std::declval` returns reference.

Comment: @Orient Yes, but what's your point? AFAIK, `decltype` on a reference yields the actual type.

Comment: @Rakete1111 https://wandbox.org/permlink/RDNHfyaf5a6ZvfwK

Comment: @Orient then you can just use a type trait to remove it :) Thanks, didn't know that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why do you *need* such a generalization? `void_t` is a little special in that it helps you easily write type traits, because you can have a primary with some type defaulted to `void` and a specialization which uses `void_t`. For instance:

```
template <class T, class = void>
struct has_prop : std::false_type { };

template <class T>
struct has_prop<T, std::void_t<decltype(T::prop)>> : std::true_type { };
```

It's not that there's anything special about `void`, you just need some agreed upon type between the primary and the specialization.

`void_t` doesn't make much sense if you're just using it directly in SFINAE though. You could just stick the expression somewhere else:

```
template <typename T, class = decltype(T::prop)>
void foo() { /* stuff */ }
```

at which point the return type is totally separate from the condition you're checking anyway, so if you want `int`:

```
template <typename T, class = decltype(T::prop)>
int foo() { /* stuff */ }
```

Comment: Why doesn't `void_t` make much sense if I'm just using it directly in SFINAE?

Comment: @Bernard `void_t` is for coercing types to `void`, but you just don't need that behavior in sfinae typically. My last 2 examples do what you want, while also having a clear return type.

Answer (score 1):

It probably does not exist. It is not linked in the documentation and therefore I doubt its existence. But you can build such type on your own:

```
template <class type, class... sfinae_expressions>
using generic_t = type;
```

Comment: OP has a better implementation of `generic_t` though. Yours doesn't take a variadic amount of arguments, which can be useful in some cases.

Comment: @Rakete1111 I added the variardic template. Now it takes a arbitrary amount of types

Comment: This simple form [might not work](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1558).

Comment: @O'Neil it's getting complicated. I was not aware of this.

Comment: @O'Neil C++17 fixes that defect, so it is guaranteed to work in a C++17-conforming compiler.